# Create a map of member functions with variadic arguments

Tags: c++, variadic

I have a class with (private) functions and different arguments. I want to put these into a map and then call them with a single function that accepts variadic arguments. I am fine to have a `bad_any_cast` on mismatching invocations (like using `v.call("Bob", 1)` in the example below). [This post solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68417073/how-to-use-one-map-to-store-different-function) is pretty close to what I want to accomplish but I cannot get it working with member functions, std::function or lambda (any of that would be fine).

Here is my minimal example I am trying to get running. My issues are the initialization of calls map and calling some any from the map. I can use anything up to C++17.

```
#include <any>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class VarCall {
public:
    VarCall() : calls({{"Alice", foo}, {"Bob", bar}, {"Charlie", baz}}) {} 

    template <typename... Args>
    void call(const string& what, Args... args) {
        any_cast<???>(calls[what])(args...);
    }

private:
    void foo() { cout << "foo()" << endl; }
    void bar(const string& s) { cout << "bar(" << s << ")" << endl; }
    void baz(int i) { cout << "baz(" << i << ")" << endl; }

    map<string, any> calls;
};

int main() {
    VarCall v;

    v.call("Alice");      //prints foo()
    v.call("Bob", "2");   //prints bar(2)
    v.call("Charlie", 1); //prints baz(1)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Always post the complete error(if any) along with your code, always.

Comment: @merula The question has been closed but I'm not sure that the linked answer is sufficient for your issue as it concerns member functions. Can you confirm that it's solved?

Comment: question completed [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76341673/correct-way-to-store-a-pointer-to-member-function-inside-stdany)